# Is it worth storing integer as string in table because it nice fits with business logic?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

In my application there are two types of users, anonymous and authenticated.
Authenticated users has integer for id, anonymous users has uuid as id. There is a table Item
which stores items that user has.
I have two ideas about how to store different id's in one table
First create column `user_id` as string and store both users ids in one column:

```
Item
+---------+----------------------------------------+----------+
| item_id |                user_id                 | quantity |
+---------+----------------------------------------+----------+
|      1  | '1'                                    |        2 |
|      2  | 'a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11' |        3 |
|      3  | '2'                                    |        1 |
+---------+----------------------------------------+----------+
```

Second create two different columns `user_id` (integer) and `anon_user_uuid` (uuid),

```
Item 
+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+----------+
| item_id | user_id |             anon_user_uuid             | quantity |
+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+----------+
|      1  | 1       | null                                   |        2 |
|      2  | null    | 'a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11' |        3 |
|      3  | 2       | null                                   |        1 |
+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+----------+
```

In first case I need to write four queries for retrieving, updating, creating, deleting items.

In second I need to write eight queries for crud operations.

So my question, is it okey to have design as in first case (first table above)?

Comment: "Authenticated users has integer for id, anonymous users has uuid as id" -- Why? It would be much simple if all users had the same type of ID; then just use a "type" column to differentiate them. Messing with the PK is sketchy.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got two completely different types of values. In that case two columns is appropriate.

The reason you'd have them as one column is so you can set up foreign keys or other relations, but that's not possible if some of these can't be matched like that.

For consistency you might want to give every user an "anonymous" ID and just use that internally. Some of these might map to a registered user, others may not.

It's also possible to just create a user record for anonymous users and if the user registers after the fact, just populate the other fields and change that status to "registered".

Comment: I see your workaround, but I think the OP should move away from this bad design.

Comment: @TheImpaler The idea of everyone using UUIDs, or even sequential IDs, is sort of what I'm suggesting here by having all users stored in the same table regardless of their "anonymous" status.